# Java regular expression with possessive quantifiers did not work?

Tags: java, regex, expression

it seems that I am completely blocked because I do not know why this code always prints "true":

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {   
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9]{1,2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("1234567");
    System.out.println(m.find());   
    }

}
```

Comment: Describe the outcome you expect and explain why you expect that outcome

Comment: There is no [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) in your regex. They look like `*+` or `?+` or `{1,2}+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matcher.find` will perform a partial match on the `String` so will always find a digit to match. You need to use `Matcher.matches()` to match the full `String`:

```
System.out.println(m.matches());
```